# Replace -fPIC with -fpic

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

When using Qt CMake automatically adds the `-fPIC` flag to compile options. I want to use `-fpic`, so I went through all Cmake variables and replaced `-fPIC` with `-fpic`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(sss)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Sql)

get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
        if (NOT "${${_variableName}}" STREQUAL "")
                string(REPLACE "-fPIC" "-fpic" ${_variableName} ${${_variableName}})
                string(REPLACE "-fPIE" "-fpie" ${_variableName} ${${_variableName}})
        endif()
        #message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
endforeach()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fpie")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-fpie -pie")

add_executable(sss main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(sss Qt5::Core Qt5::Sql)
```

`main.cpp` contains

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>

int main(){
        QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
}
```

Unfortunately CMake still adds the `-fPIC` flag, althoguh the listed variables does not contain it:

```
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sss.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SQL_LIB -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql  -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/sss.dir/main.cpp.o -c src/main.cpp
```

How can I replace `-fPIC` with `-fpic`?

Comment: I think this comes from Qt itself (see [here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=16002)). It sets [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) to `-fPIC`. Try adding `set_property(TARGET Qt5::Core PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-fpic")` after `find_package()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Your code overwrites CMake global variables like `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OPTIONS_PIC` or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OPTIONS_PIE`.

But Qt brings its own `-fPIC` option through target properties. The `Qt5::Core` target does have [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) set to `-fPIC` (see e.g. [here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=16002)).

Try overwriting the target properties by adding

```
set_property(TARGET Qt5::Core PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-fpic")
```

after your `find_package(Qt5 ...)` call.