# cmake: adding C++ standard when not required

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

When building a C++ executable under Linux using cmake 3.7, I see a `-std=gnu++11` flag being added to compile flags. The problem is, I'm already manually adding a `-std=c++1z` flag, and this new one overwrites mine. This happens only for executables, but I cannot find this being mentioned in the docs. The `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` is empty, and setting the `CXX_STANDARD` property on the target has no effect. Is there a way to remove this flag?

This seems to be not only limited to executables.

Here's my (simplified) cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z")    
find_boost(serialization system)    
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)    
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${ZMQ_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${CPPZMQ_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

if(WIN32)
    add_definitions(-DNOMINMAX)
endif()

add_executable(
    ${PROFILER_CLIENT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    MainWindow.cpp
    MainWindow.h
    ProfilerWidget.cpp
    ProfilerWidget.h
    TimelineWidget.cpp
    TimelineWidget.h
    ZmqReceiver.cpp
    ZmqReceiver.h
)

add_dependencies(${PROFILER_CLIENT_NAME} boost zeromq)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROFILER_CLIENT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ${PROFILER_NAME}
    PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets
)
```

Comment: Like with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053846/replace-fpic-with-fpic) question I assume that Qt5 or Boost is bringing this option with it. So what do you get with `get_target_property(_flags ${PROFILER_CLIENT_NAME} INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS)` and `message("_flags = ${_flags}")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @florian suspected, it's Qt5 that's polluting your compile commands. Using a similar `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z")
set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55")
execute_process(COMMAND brew --prefix qt5
  COMMAND tr -d \\n
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE QT5_BREW_PATH)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS serialization system)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets HINTS ${QT5_BREW_PATH})

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo
  PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets
  )
```

I configured and built a dummy executable. You can plainly see the `-std=c++1z` and the `-std=gnu++11` on the compile line:

```
❯ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -H/Users/nega/foo -B/Users/nega/foo --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/nega/foo/CMakeFiles /Users/nega/foo/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/foo.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/foo.dir/depend
cd /Users/nega/foo && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/nega/foo /Users/nega/foo /Users/nega/foo /Users/nega/foo /Users/nega/foo/CMakeFiles/foo.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/foo.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/foo.dir/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/include -iframework /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -isystem /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/./mkspecs/macx-clang  -std=c++1z   -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/nega/foo/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable foo
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/foo.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++1z -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o  -o foo  -L/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib /usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib /usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/QtWidgets /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtGui.framework/QtGui /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore 
[100%] Built target foo
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/nega/foo/CMakeFiles 0
```

If you comment out the Qt5 usage in our `CMakeLists.txt` and configure and build again, you'll see the `-std=gnu++11` disappear (along with the `-fPIC` which Qt is also adding).

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z")
set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55")
execute_process(COMMAND brew --prefix qt5
  COMMAND tr -d \\n
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE QT5_BREW_PATH)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS serialization system)
#find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets HINTS ${QT5_BREW_PATH})

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo
  PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
# PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets
  )
```

**`make` output (abridged):**

```
[...]
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -I/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/include  -std=c++1z   -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/nega/foo/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable foo
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/foo.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++1z -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o  -o foo  -L/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib /usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib /usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib 
[100%] Built target foo
[...]
```

Unfortunately, after some brief digging I couldn't see where Qt was setting `-std=gnu++11` in its `*Config.cmake` files. It must be reaching into CMake more than just a few `grep`'s could find. Maybe reading through `cmake --trace` will provide some insight.

Curiously though, what ever it's doing respects `CXX_STANDARD`. If we tweak our original `CMakeLists.txt` and configure and build again:

**CMakeLists.txt (abridged):**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z")
set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55")
execute_process(COMMAND brew --prefix qt5
[...]
```

**`make` output (abridged):**

```
[...]
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -I/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/include -iframework /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -isystem /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt5/./mkspecs/macx-clang  -std=c++1z   -fPIC -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/nega/foo/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable foo
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/foo.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++1z -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o  -o foo  -L/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib /usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib /usr/local/opt/boost@1.55/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/QtWidgets /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtGui.framework/QtGui /usr/local/opt/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore 
[100%] Built target foo
[...]
```

You can see that the (Qt added) `-fPIC -std=gnu++11` is now `-fPIC -std=gnu++14`. Unfortunately this won't help you until CMake 3.8.0 is released and its `CXX_STANDARD`/`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` [will understand "C++17"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html?highlight=17).